# Show that if $F/K^\sigma $ is normale then $\operatorname{Aut}_{K^\sigma }(F)\to \operatorname{Aut}_{K^\sigma }(K)$ is surjective.

Tags: field-theory

I'm totally stuck on the following question:

> Show that if $F/K^\sigma $ is normale then $\operatorname{Aut}_{K^\sigma }(F)\to \operatorname{Aut}_{K^\sigma }(K)$ is surjective where $K^\sigma $ is the set of fix point of $\sigma $ over $K$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $F/K$ is algebraic,
$$\Phi: \text{Hom}_{K^\sigma }(F,K^{\sigma ,alg})\longrightarrow \text{Hom}_{K^\sigma }(K,K^{\sigma, alg}) $$
defined by $$\Phi(\psi)=\psi|_K$$
is surjective.

If you can prove that $K/K^\sigma $ is normale, you will have your result.

Comment: It's true, I have such a theorem. I already tried to prove that $K/K^\sigma $ is normale, but with no success.